# Обработка запроса перед его отправкой

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть кнопка:

`<input id="makeBetButton" type="submit" value="Создать ставку" onclick="return confirmSubm()"/>`

Мне нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку "создать ставку" выскакивало подтверждение, а в это время на сервер отправляется запрос, который проверяет можно ли создать ставку или нет, если ставку создать нельзя, то действие (submit) не должно выполняться.

Функция подтверждения действия:

```
function confirmSubm() {
     if (confirm("Подтвердите действие")) {
         return setTimeout(ajaxreqqwerty, 0);
     }
     else
         return false;
 }
```

Ajax запрос:

```
function ajaxreqqwerty() {
                var data = {"matchId":"${sessionScope.match.id}", "command":"CHECK_TIME_AJAX"};

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    url: 'ajax_controller',
                    success: [function(serverData) { //Если запрос удачен
                        if (serverData.serverInfo === "true") {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            $("#resultCheckTime").text("Время ставок истекло"); //добавление текста в блок чтобы показать пользователю почему действие не прошло
                            return false;
                        }
                    }]
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function confirmSubm() {
  if (confirm("Подтвердите действие")) {
    ajaxreqqwerty();
  }
  return false;
}

function ajaxreqqwerty() {
  var data = {"matchId":"${sessionScope.match.id}", "command":"CHECK_TIME_AJAX"};

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url: 'ajax_controller',
    success: function(serverData) { //Если запрос удачен
      if (serverData.serverInfo === "true") {
        document.forms[0].submit();
      } else {
        $("#resultCheckTime").text("Время ставок истекло"); 
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: А если у меня в документе будет несколько форм, я смогу за раз все обработать?